# SqlDataAdapter in c#: Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using C# to write a program that runs a stored procedure on our database and writes the data to an Excel sheet before emailing that sheet to coworkers.

I'm using a `SqlDataAdapter` to store the data. The stored procedure has 1 parameter with 4 possible values. When I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio, everything runs fine.

But the same procedure in C# returns an arithmetic overflow error. The code fails on the `dataAdapter.Fill(ds)` line

```
using (SqlConnection conn = gobjUtility.TigerConnection = gcnxnTiger)
{
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strStoredProcedure, conn);
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 200;

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@LocCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = " ";                   

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    dataAdapter.Fill(ds);

    int count = ds.Tables.Count;
}
```

Comment: It generally happens for invalid cast related exception. Please share the stored procedure for better understanding.

Comment: I think you want to focus your efforts on the contents of the Stored Procedure. There is no mathematical operation in `dataAdapter.Fill(ds)` All that line will do is execute the Sql against the database

Comment: Come on format left and list the server.

Comment: Add a try/catch around this code (or just the dataAdapter.Fill) and inspect the exception. What are the exact details (please edit into your question)? In particular, is there some SqlException (possibly as InnerException) that points to an error in your stored procedure?